# Polkadot relay chain node source code walkthrough/explanation

Tags: polkadot, relay-chain, documentation

Is there any documentation/tutorials covering the technical details behind the Polkadot relay chain source code, specifically the runtime where all the special logic of the relay chain occurs? I am referring to the code in this repo: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot. So far, the tutorials I have found mainly deal with creating new blockchains with Substrate.

For instance, if I was trying to change the relay chain such that parachains don't need to be auctioned off and can only be used by people with the admin (sudo) key, I would need to understand how the relay chain source code works and is organized. Any resources are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web3 foundation maintains a detailed specification doc of both the [polkadot host](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-polkadot-host) and the runtime, you can it find it [here](https://spec.polkadot.network/#_runtime_specification). However, note that this document may be outdated in certain sections, the source of truth is always found in [the current release of the runtime](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/releases/tag/v0.9.24).

Moreover, note that Polkadot is built with Substrate, hence Substrate tutorials and doc covering the Sudo pallet will be relevant to your concrete example.